# Extract specific columns from multiple workbooks and consolidate and report

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here][1]

I have multiple workbooks in a folder, I need to retrieve data from specific columns by concatenating the data. Consolidate the data and prepare a report. Details explanation given below

/workbook 1 name - sg  subsystem : copy contents of the columns ( A, B, H , I ) into main sheet

[enter image description here][1]

Workbook 2 name : sg main system , copy contents of ( A, b, F, I )

[enter image description here][2]

into main sheet

The main sheet should contain details of the two worksheet in the below format . 
contents of A of workbooks , col B of workbooks, common key of two sheets (curr + Gl account ) ,  Revenue ( col I data of workbooks ) , difference in revenue

Comment: So you “need to retrieve data from specific columns”? And what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Hi , thanks for revert . I am unable to prepare macro . It will be great if you can help with a macro . Am unable to put the expected result here in this space as the site is not allowing me coz of lack of points . Happy to mail . Thanks .  My ID _guru.sssihl2012@gmail.com